# Selenium Grid 2 - Start Node as a windows service

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run tests with on a remote m/c using grid 2. So I have a Hub running on my computer and a Node running on a Remote m/c and I can run my tests without any issues. However, to smoothen the experience I want to run the hub and the node as a windows service. This way i can manage the hub and node in the code. So I installed the Hub as a service on the server and Node as a service on the Remote m/c using srvany as shown below

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Instsrv.exe RunHub C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Srvany.exe

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Instsrv.exe RunNode C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Srvany.exe  (where RunHub and RunNode are batch files)

I also made the necessary changes in the registry.

The issue I'm facing is that when I run the node as a windows service in the remote m/c, it is not registering itself correctly to the hub. When I look at the grid overview(http://localhost:4444/grid/console) i do not see the node there. However, if I run the same bat file manually and not as a service everything works fine. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Or what's the best way to troubleshoot this?

thanks,

---

Ok I figured this out myself. There was a reference to a file in a different directory in the bat files. This file could not be accessed when running it as a service. I moved the file to the correct dir and now i can run the Node service