# Should we register a node daily in selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

Do we need to register a node every time in selenium grid ? I registered a node today and ran the test cases, tomorrow when i come i don't want to register it again, instead i just want to run the test cases. How to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own knowledge from running hub and nodes:

I have dedicated machine to run hub and nodes. I started hub and registered nodes and then did some tests. After sucessful run, I kept running the node and hub on that machine.

Next day, I realised that everything runs and I can continue the testing.

So general advice:

- keep the nodes running. It will consume some processor time and RAM, but it will make your testing faster
- If you want, you can make the node as service. See this SO question: [Selenium Grid 2 - Start Node as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627826/selenium-grid-2-start-node-as-a-windows-service)
- Down side is that it will consume some resources of the machine. But that is the decission you have to make...